# GridView Custom PagerTemplate, Show Hide Previous and Next Links

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have the following PagerTemplate. I need to hide the Previous link when user is viewing the first page and hide the Next link if user is viewing the Last page.

```
                <PagerTemplate>
                    <table border="0" style="width: 100%;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="float: right;">
                                    <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" ID="LinkButton2" runat="server"><< Previous</asp:LinkButton>
                                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" >Next >></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                                <td style="clear: both"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </PagerTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grid's `PageIndex` and `PageCount` properties will help you here - Prev link should be shown/enabled only when `PageIndex > 0` while Next link should be shown/enabled only when `PageIndex < PageCount - 1`.

Use row created event to find controls and alter the visibility. For example,

```
protected void GridView_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
    {
       var prev = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton2");
       prev.Visible = Grid.PageIndex > 0;

       var next = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton3");
       next.Visible = Grid.PageIndex < grid.PageCount -  1;
    }
}
```

I am not sure of you need a custom template for current UI. You can use pager settings - for example,

```
<pagersettings mode="NextPrevious"
            nextpagetext="Next >>"
            previouspagetext="<< Previos"   
            position="Bottom"/>
```

And use PagerStyle for styling the UI.

```
<PagerStyle CssClass="myPager" />
```